# Unique constraint keys not invoked when a field is NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named **AQI**, with the following column
[image]

Only one **unique** value of `date`, `pollutant_code`, `source_id` and `time` are able to exist, so I defined a unique constraint `source_code_time_uq`.

And the upsert query like

```
INSERT INTO aqi(source_id, source_type, pollutant_code, "date", "time", aqi_value)
VALUES (4, 1 ,'PM2.5','2018-05-28',8, 789)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT source_code_time_uq
DO UPDATE SET
    aqi_value = 789
```

The upsert method work normally when all the field available, but when I put `NULL` in the `time` column (in an attempt to make that row represent AQI data for a whole day), the `source_code_time_uq` constraint doesn't invoked and it still insert a new row.

So how can I add unique constraint check on the field that can also be `NULL` , do I need to update my upsert query ?

Comment: Is this really SQL Server? Syntax doesn't look like it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_aqi_4 on (date, pollutant_code, source_id, time)
    where time is not null;
```

Then, you probably also want to guarantee only one `NULL` row per day, so:

```
create unique index unq_aqi_4 on (date, pollutant_code, source_id)
    where time is null;
```

Of course, remove the `unique` constraint as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with unique constraint is that it will allow one null so we might have to define the column as not null .Hope this helps